# Unable to link LiveCode to Android SDK

Tags: android, macos, sdk, livecode

This is my first question on this forum, i'm really sorry if i missed something that i was unable to find by my multiple search efforts.

I am am using a 16GB Ram Mac upgraded to Maverick 10.9, i have just purchased the Livecode Commercial package (6.5.1-RC-1)

I have successfully linked the IOS SDK to the Mobile Support Preference list.

I've attempted to load the Android SDK without success. :(

When navigating and selecting the Android SDK Folder /Users/macuser/Documents/My LiveCode/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/SDK i get the error message:

"The chosen folder is not an Android SDK, please ensure you have installed it correctly and enabled support for  Android 2.2 (Froyo)"

I've noticed others have also encountered this, but i've not seen how they solved it :(

In attempt to ensure i have loaded everything, i have followed the steps on this link with success all the way up to and including Starting the Virtual Device Simulator.

http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/2571/l/27389-how-do-i-become-an-android-developer-on-a-mac

Thank you in advance for any guidance on next steps.

Joe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Those guys here suggest using an older version of the SDK http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?t=15215

Comment: I think I've discovered the answer. The error message was more helpful that i expected.. and i'm feeling pretty foolish!

So.. In the Android SDK Manager Dialog Box there's a list of Android versions that you can download. At this time the current version is Android 4.4 (Kit Kat?) but if you don't go all the way back and select the SDK's associated with version 2.2 then the Livecode seems unsatisfied :). Makes total sense.. since it tells you in the error message that it is in fact looking for the Froyo release.

Comment: So if this happens to you.. open the Android SDK Manager Dialog box. You can find it in the Android ADT Application under the 'Window' menu item and selecting the 'Android SDK Manager' list item. This will launch the Android SDK Manager dialog box. Then select the Android 2.2 (API 8) folder, check it, accept the license and download it. Then go back to Livecode and link to the SDK Folder /Users/macuser/Documents/My LiveCode/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/SDK and no error will be raised.

Hope this helps someone that happened to ignore the obvious like me :)

-Joe

Comment: Well done in finding a solution! I suggest you post the solution as an answer and accept it, so the question is marked as closed and another SO user with the same problem can find it more easily

Comment: will do.. i tried to do that already, but because i'm still such a noob i have to wait at least 8 hours to answer my own question :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I've discovered the answer.

The error message was more helpful that i expected.. and i'm feeling pretty foolish! So.. In the Android SDK Manager Dialog Box there's a list of Android versions that you can download. At this time the current version is Android 4.4 (Kit Kat?) but if you don't go all the way back and select the SDK's associated with version 2.2 then the Livecode seems unsatisfied :). Makes total sense.. since it tells you in the error message that it is in fact looking for the Froyo release.

So if this happens to you.. open the Android SDK Manager Dialog box. You can find it in the Android ADT Application under the 'Window' menu item and selecting the 'Android SDK Manager' list item. This will launch the Android SDK Manager dialog box. Then select the Android 2.2 (API 8) folder, check it, accept the license and download it. Then go back to Livecode and link to the SDK Folder /Users/macuser/Documents/My LiveCode/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/SDK and no error will be raised. Hope this helps someone that happened to ignore the obvious like me :) -Joe